# how to replace two arrays that have different values into the same value between the two arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm learning python arrays and I'm having trouble solving this code

```html
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

a = b
print(a)
print(b)
```

I want to change the value of array b to be the same as the value of array a. like this:

```html
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

but the result is like this:

```html
a = [6,7,8,9,10]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

what I want is the value of a is equal to b not vice versa. can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Yoıu want to assign the value of `a` to `b`? `b = a.copy()`

Comment: subtract 5 for each term in `b`

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning in the different order. You would like to assign list b to the value a not the other way around.
But as lists are mutable, I would suggest doing

```
b = a.copy()
```

Otherwise you would modify b when you modify a.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output, you can also try: `b = a`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly you can use:

```py
b = a.copy() # as mentioned in other comments

#or

b = a[:]
```

This way the value of a will be assigned to b. At the same time if you change any of them the other one will not change.